# How to do remote system maintainance on friends/family PC?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, remote-assistance

I have a raspberry pi with a working ddns set up.

I want to create a simple system through which I can do system maintainance on Linux systems of my friends/family PC.

The workflow that I have in mind is the following: by launching a given program, they allow a particular user on the raspberry to access their pc with their current user via ssh; they also see a window that can be closed to remove the access permission.

I was imaging this workflow with a custom script spawning a reverse ssh tunneling, but this implies some initial setup for routers, firewalls, `ssh-keygen`, `ssh-copy-id`, etc, and considering they are newbies, it's not that easy for them.

I am looking for other solutions...

Comment: I believe that more information is needed. Are these family members running their systems on another network completely separate from yours? Are these systems strictly CLI based or do they have GUI as well? What sort of maintenance are you referring to in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with creating a tool for this:

https://github.com/00sapo/launch_assistance